# Can this type of graph be analysed to produce any meaningful data?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, data-analysis

[image]

The above is a graph of pendulum length on the x-axis measured in metres, and pendulum period on the y axis measured in seconds. **The pendulum period is not squared**.

If I square the pendulum period, I can apply that to the g formula used for calculating gravity using pendulum motion. However, what if it is not squared - is there a purpose to this graph apart from showing the proportional relationship. Can the gradient tell us anything? I am not required to analyse it any further than squaring it, but just out of interest I wonder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Speaking as an (ex) experimental scientist, graphing the raw data straight from your experiment is an excellent idea because it gives you a basic view of how large the experimental errors are, i.e. how scattered the data is, and sometimes gives you a clue to the function behind the data. In this case you can see at a glance that the errors in your measurement of time are about a quarter of a second.

However you've graphed the data over too small a range to get a useful idea of the function behind it. This is a graph of your data with the calculated period $\tau = 2\pi\sqrt{l/g}$ shown by the blue line:

[image: Pendulum]

The curve is a parabola, but over the relative short range of lengths it doesn't look very different to the straight line you've drawn on your graph. It's hard to tell what the functional form is by looking at the graph.

So your graph is of limited use as it stands. It's not without use - for example you were obviously having an off moment when you measured the period for $l = 0.8$m - but it's not useful for exploring the physics behind the measurements.

Incidentally, it's generally bad practice to draw lines unless you have some physical reason to do so. drawing the fitted straight line is fair enough, but you shouldn't draw the lines connecting the points.

Comment: This answers my question perfectly. The general trend I believe at higher values is a proportional relationship with diminishing returns the further the x axis extends.